# How can I synchronize adding a new CALayer object with animations of another object

Tags: ios, animation

I have two CALayer objects -- layer1, layer2.  I want to perform the following actions --

- add layer1 to a view's layer user addSublayer:
- move layer1 to a new position using a CABasicAnimation
- add layer2 to the view's layer
- move layer2 to a new position

This, without layer2 showing until layer1's animation is complete.

I have attempted this by setting beginTime on the animation of layer2 to the end time of layer1's animation -- but layer2 shows during the gap before it's begin time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered one method for achieving my result.  I'm not sure it's the best way to do it, so would still be grateful for other ideas.

I create layer1 and layer2 at the same time and addSublayer both to the the view.layer.  Then I animate layer1 to move it to a new position, duration = 0.3.  For layer2 I animate with a group which consists of a move (beginTime = 0.3, duration = 0.3) and another animation using the hidden attribute.  The latter animation hides layer2 immediately and then unhides it at beginTime = 0.3.  To achieve the latter animation I used a CAKeyFrameAnimation because this animation must be discrete -- either fully hidden or fully unhidden.

Here's the code.  I simplified it by removing details about my implementation, so this is not the actual code in my app -- apologies if there are any errors.

```
CALayer layer1 = [CALayer layer];
CALayer layer2 = [CALayer layer];

/*
 * set attributes of the layers -- cut out of this example
 */
layer1.position = toPosition1;  // positions when animation is complete
layer2.position = toPosition2;

[myView.layer addSublayer:layer1];
[myView.layer addSublayer:layer2];

// animate layer 1
CABasicAnimation* move1 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
move1.duration = 0.3;
move1.fromValue = fromPosition2;
[layer1 addAnimation:move1 forKey:nil];

// animate layer 2 with a group
CABasicAnimation* move2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
move2.duration = 0.3;
move2.fromValue = fromPosition2;
move2.beginTime = 0.3;

CAKeyframeAnimation *show = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"hidden"];
show.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], nil];
// times are given as fractions of the duration time -- hidden for first 50% of 0.6 sec
show.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
show.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete;
show.duration = 0.6;
show.beginTime = 0;

CAAnimationGroup *grp = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
[grp setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:move2, show, nil ]];
grp.duration = 0.6;

[layer2 addAnimation:grp forKey:nil];
```

I